# Using dynamic variables in URL

Tags: gps, tinygps

I am trying to upload longitude and latitude data into MySQK using a GPRS shield, Arduino Uno R3 and a GPS module. The idea is to get longitude and latitude data from the GPS and use the GPRS to post the information into my database.

I have to insert the latitude and longitude data into the URL like  this `steetalert.co.zw/write_data.php?Longitude=12.124311,Latitude=27,766785`. Values for longitude and latitude have to be dynamic not static. How do I go about this?

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate place to ask people to write entire programs for you. Post the code you've got so far and explain where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to know how to create a string that contains:
`steetalert.co.zw/write_data.php?Longitude=12.124311,Latitude=27,766785`

Its quite easy (I think) try this:

```
const int cDecimalPlaces(6);
String szLon = String(fLongitude, cDecimalPlaces);
String szLat = String(fLatitude, cDecimalPlaces);
String szUrl = "steetalert.co.zw/write_data.php?Longitude=" + szLon ",Latitude=" + szLat;
```

Normally I would use sprint or a Format function, but I can't find those in the reference.